# EntitySqlException when trying to access DbUpdateConcurrencyException's GetDatabaseValues() entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm trying to do the tutorial here: http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

In the ActionResult Edit, I have the following code:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Product product)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {

                        var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
        var databaseValuesObj = entry.GetDatabaseValues().ToObject();
        var databaseValues = (Product)databaseValuesObj;
        var clientValues = (Product)entry.Entity;
        if (databaseValues.Name != clientValues.Name)
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Current value: "
                + databaseValues.Name);
        if (databaseValues.Description != clientValues.Description)
            ModelState.AddModelError("Description", "Current value: "
                + String.Format("{0:c}", databaseValues.Description));
        if (databaseValues.ControllingStudentId != clientValues.ControllingStudentId)
            ModelState.AddModelError("ControllingStudentId", "Current value: "
                + String.Format("{0:d}", databaseValues.ControllingStudentId));
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to edit "
            + "was modified by another user after you got the original value. The "
            + "edit operation was canceled and the current values in the database "
            + "have been displayed. If you still want to edit this record, click "
            + "the Save button again. Otherwise click the Back to List hyperlink.");
        product.Timestamp = databaseValues.Timestamp;
    }
    catch (DataException)
    {
        //Log the error (add a variable name after Exception)
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator.");
    }

    return View(product);
}
```

On the `var databaseValuesObj = entry.GetDatabaseValues().ToObject();` line, I get an exception like this:

```
System.Data.EntitySqlException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Type 'MvcApplication3.DAL.Product' could not be found. Make sure that the required schemas are loaded and that the namespaces are imported correctly. Near type name, line 1, column 119.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  Column=119
  ErrorContext=type name, line 1, column 119
  ErrorDescription=Type 'MvcApplication3.DAL.Product' could not be found. Make sure that the required schemas are loaded and that the namespaces are imported correctly.
  Line=1
 ...
```

My question is, how can I show it where the Product class is?  Its in the project and I've got the using statement at the top.  Why can't it find it?

Edit:
Based on the response below, I changed my code to:

```
        var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
        var currentValues = entry.CurrentValues.Clone();
        entry.Reload();
        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(currentValues);
        var clientValues = (Product)entry.Entity;
        var databaseValues = (Product)entry.OriginalValues.ToObject();
```

And that seemed to fix it.  But I think it will have issues if the row is deleted.  My current problem won't have that issue, so this is a good fix for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue when the context is in a different projects. No workarounds currently exist except for moving the context into the same project.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-HK/adodotnetentityframework/thread/fa67aa0e-3bca-44a5-9e00-af6362a539a7

*EDIT*
Actually I take that back - there is a workaround now listed there since the last time I read this. cool : )